# Relation between weighted sum of squares and weighted sum

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a relation between $$X = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i x_i\quad  \text{and} \quad X' = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i x_i ^2?$$

We can assume that $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i =1$ and $\forall i\in[1,n], p_i \geq 0$ (basically, the $p_i$'s in my case are normalized weights).

I know when $p_1 = p_2 = \dots = p_n = p$, we have a special case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and get the relation: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i ^2 \geq \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2}{n}.$$

My question is: Is there any known lower bound or relation linking the two sums when the weights are not equal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function $f(x) = x^2$ is convex, you can apply [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) to get:

$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i x_i\right)^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^n p_i x_i^2
$$

Comment: beautiful! thanks!

Comment: @RDN Happy to help!